# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java_cup.runtime.lr_parser.getSymbolFactory()Ljava_cup/runtime/SymbolFactory

Tags: java, jflex

A project I just started working on uses JFlex, and when I try and compile the project using `ant`, I get the following error:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java_cup.runtime.lr_parser.getSymbolFactory()Ljava_cup/runtime/SymbolFactory`

What's causing this? I have the JFlex jar downloaded, and am using it in my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out to use the `jflex` ant tasks, you need to [download JFlex from here](http://jflex.de/download.html), unzip it somewhere, then copy the `jflex-1.6.1/lib/*` files to your `ant/lib/` folder, and try again.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when using both `JFlex.jar` and `cup_v10k.jar` in the same project in IntelliJ.

The problem lied in the `cup_v10k.jar`, where the `java_cup.runtime.lr_parser` class also exists, and the method `getSymbolFactory()` does not exist in that class.

IntelliJ didn't know which jar to trust when searching for the `lr_parser` class, and chose the lexicographically first jar - `cup_v10k.jar`.

My solution/hack was to rename the `cup_v10k.jar` to something lexicographically after `JFlex.jar`, for example `zcup_v10k.jar`. IntelliJ was then able to find the right `lr_parser` class.